# How to hardcode file type while creating it using ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating file using

```
private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) { uri ->
        uri?.let { writeToFile(requireActivity(), it) }
    }
```

and then launch it:

```
getContent.launch("file.csv")
```

so when i'm in launcher i can rename file before saving and also change file type which is not what i expect. So can i let user change name but hardcore this type?

Answer (score 0):

```
private val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
{ result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //  make action
    }

}

private fun createFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = "image/png"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "AA.png")
    startForResult.launch(intent)
}
```